# Old&New urine smell &Stains

Tags: dogs

I have 3 dogs(with behavioral issues) who will not stop peeing on the carpet. I have tried vinegar and baking soda, it just seemed to make it worse or not at all. The smell is very strong & unpleasant! What else can help me?!? I don't want to waste $$ on store products that may or may not work.

Comment: Usually urine spray cleaners contain enzymes to break down the smell of the ammonia, which is what you'd look for in a store product.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's a perfect product that totally eliminates the smell. We were forced to replace carpeting in two rooms with laminate flooring, which solved the problem.